# Can Onclicking a button carry two functions. . .?

Tags: javascript, html

As I am new to javascript and jQuery, I like to ask that for example: can a button on clicking it changes its value and also add an item in a cart table. And when it is clicked again the value of the button should change to the previous value and also remove the item from the cart

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Just add a handler that calls the two functions.

It's a single handler, but it does two things.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are after some very basic programming. I would recommend an `if` statement for this sort of thing.

With jQuery you can use the `hasClass()` method to check if a button has a certain class as below.

```
$('.button').click(function(){        

    if($(this).hasClass('clicked')) {
        // Do Second Action
        $(this).removeClass('clicked');
    } else {
        // Do First Action
        $(this).addClass('clicked');
    }

});
```

Here is a really quick example of how you can use this along with css to change the state of a button http://jsfiddle.net/Tx7j5/